# Функция 0x06 Modbus RTU C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, modbus

Нашел неплохой пример для работы с протоколом Modbus RTU
[Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20929/Simple-Modbus-Protocol-in-C-NET)

Все бы ничего, но там нет реализации функции 0x06. Есть только 16 функция записи нескольких регистров. Как ее переделать в функцию 0х06

```
   // sp это у меня SerialPort sp = new SerialPort private void 
    BuildMessage(byte address, byte type, ushort start, ushort registers, 
                                                       ref byte[] message)
    {
        // Массив для CRC bytes:
        byte[] CRC = new byte[2];

        message[0] = address;
        message[1] = type;
        message[2] = (byte)(start >> 8);
        message[3] = (byte)start;
        message[4] = (byte)(registers >> 8);
        message[5] = (byte)registers;

        // Функция подсчета CRC
        GetCRC(message, ref CRC);
        message[message.Length - 2] = CRC[0];
        message[message.Length - 1] = CRC[1];
      }

          public bool SendFc16(byte address, ushort start, ushort registers, 
           short[] values)
          {
            // Проверяю открыт ли порт
            if (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                //Очишаю буфер
                sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
                sp.DiscardInBuffer();
                //Сообщение 1 адрес + 1 функция + 2 старт + 2 регистр + 1 счетчик + 2 * значение регистров + 2 CRC
                byte[] message = new byte[9 + 2 * registers];
                //ответ 16 функции фиксированный и занимает 8 байт
                byte[] response = new byte[8];

                // Счетчик байт в сообщении:
                message[6] = (byte)(registers * 2);
                // Пишем:
                for (int i = 0; i < registers; i++)
                {
                    message[7 + 2 * i] = (byte)(values[i] >> 8);
                    message[8 + 2 * i] = (byte)(values[i]);
                }
                //Наше сообщение:
                BuildMessage(address, (byte)16, start, registers, ref message);
            }

            if (ну тут организация проверки записи)
            {
                // Запись успешна;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Ошибка CRC;
                return false;
            }
    }
```

По идее тут:

```
BuildMessage(address, (byte)16, start, registers, ref message);
```

Заменить на так:

```
BuildMessage(address, (byte)6, start, registers, ref message);
```

И вот тут что-то надо поменять, в формировании посылки в сообщении, только что не могу разобрать:

```
// Счетчик байт в сообщении:
                message[6] = (byte)(registers * 2);
                // Пишем:
                for (int i = 0; i < registers; i++)
                {
                    message[7 + 2 * i] = (byte)(values[i] >> 8);
                    message[8 + 2 * i] = (byte)(values[i]);
                }
```

Подскажите как тут сделать запись в один регистр. Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция 06 не имеет вариативной части в неё всегда передается значение одного регистра. Соотвествено размер пакета всегда равен 8 байтам. В вашем коде вы выделяете не правильное кол-во байт для пакета(`new byte[9 + 2 * registers]`).

Вот пример как создавать пакеты для функций 05 и 06

```
class AluCreator
{
    // создает пакет для функции 05
    public static byte[] CreateAlu05(byte address, byte function, ushort coilAddress, bool coilValue)
    {
        ushort coilValueShort = 0;
        if (coilValue) {
            coilValueShort = 0xFF00;
        }

        return CreateSingleValueWriteAlu(address, 0x05, coilAddress, coilValueShort);
    }

    // создает пакет для функции 06
    public static byte[] CreateAlu06(byte address, byte function, ushort regAddress, ushort regValue)
    {
        return CreateSingleValueWriteAlu(address, 0x06, regAddress, regValue);
    }

    private static byte[] CreateSingleValueWriteAlu(byte address, byte function, ushort regAddress, ushort regValue)
    {
        var result = new byte[8];

        result[0] = address;
        result[1] = function;
        result[2] = (byte)(regAddress >> 8);
        result[3] = (byte)regAddress;
        result[4] = (byte)(regValue >> 8);
        result[5] = (byte)regValue;

        var crc = GetCRC(result, 6);

        result[6] = (byte)crc;
        result[7] = (byte)(crc >> 8);

        return result;
    }

    private static ushort GetCRC(byte[] data, int dataCount)
    {
        ushort crc = 0xFFFF;
        for(int pos = 0; pos < dataCount; pos++) {
            crc ^= (UInt16)data[pos];
            for(int i = 8; i != 0; i--) {
                if((crc & 0x0001) != 0) {
                    crc >>= 1;
                    crc ^= 0xA001;
                }
                else {
                    crc >>= 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return crc;
    }
}
```

**PS:**
Вообще на [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus) очень хорошо описана структура пакетов(посмотрите табличку **PDU запроса и ответа для стандартных функций**). Если сухое описание не очень понимается посмотрите примеры пакетов в интернете(например [тут](http://www.simplymodbus.ca/FC06.htm)).

Comment: Огромное человеческое спасибо Вам за помощь и наводку! Буду курить и набивать шишки. Спасибо еще раз.